# How do the instance variables effect the values of my constructors here?

Tags: java, variables, constructor

I am working through a java exercise and am somewhat confused what the new values of the last 4 lines of code are.

```
public class Snake {
    public Snake x = null;
    public Snake y = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Snake a = new Snake();
        Snake b = new Snake();
        a.x = a;
        b.x = a.x;
        b.y = b.x;
        a.y = b.y.x;
    }
}
```

Comment: You just have an object with a property that points to the object itself... and that's a little like the beginning of infinity :-)

Comment: By the end both X and Y fields of A and B are equal to A. Whoever authored this exercise is an idiot. It's like trying to teach someone English with ["how much wood would a woodchuck chuck"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_much_wood_would_a_woodchuck_chuck)

Answer (score 1):

Then you understood that `a` and `b` are two snakes. But they are really references to two different snakes.

`a.x = a` : means make `a.x` refer to snake referred by `a`.

`b.x = a.x` : means make `b.x` refer to snake referred by `a.x` (so the same as `a`).

`b.y = b.x` : means make `b.y` refer to snake referred by `b.x` (so the same as `a`).

`a.y = b.y.x`: means make `a.y` refer to snake referred by `b.y.x`, as `b.y` refers to `a`, this refers to `a.x` which is the same as `a`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works:

```
a.x = a;
```

the `x` Snake object (property) of the `a` Snake object becomes a reference (points) to the `a` Snake object itself.

```
b.x = a.x;
```

the `x` Snake object (property) of the `b` Snake object becomes a reference (points) to the `a.x` Snake object which previously was set to refer to the `a` Snake object. 
 So this `b.x` also becomes a reference (points) to the `a` Snake object .

```
b.y = b.x;
```

the `y` Snake object (property) of the `b` Snake object becomes a reference (points) to the `b.x` Snake object which previously was set to refer to the `a` Snake object. 
 So this `b.y` also becomes a reference (points) to the `a` Snake object .

```
a.y = b.y.x;
```

the `y` Snake object (property) of the `a` Snake object becomes a reference (points) to the `b.y.x` Snake object and since `b.y` was previously set to `a` it is equivalent to `a.x` which previously was set to refer to the `a` Snake object. 
 So this `a.y` also becomes a reference (points) to the `a` Snake object .

 
**Finally**: all the left parts of the assignments refer (point) to `a`.